# Restrictions on Canonical NaNs in IEEE 754-2008

Tags: floating-point, standards, nan, ieee-754

The usage of canonical NaN in the standard is confusing to me. For binary floats, it doesn't actually state what a canonical NaN is. For decimal floats it states (paeg 11):

> A NaN is in its preferred (canonical) representation if the bits G_6 through G_(w+4) are zeroand the encoding of the payload is canonical.

The only restriction I can find on binary floats is that there should be a canonical version of any NaN. Therefore at least 1 NaN must exist per bit-width.

Is there an upper bound on the number of canonical NaNs that can be allowed? Can every NaN be canonical?

Comment: In binary floating-point formats, I think every NaN is canonical. The rules for canonical are primarily decimal formats, where there may be representations of the same number with different exponents (such as 3•10^1 and 30•10^0) or bit patterns in the 10-bit declets outside the 1000 canonical patterns. A canonical NaN uses the canonical exponent and canonical bit patterns even though it is not encoding a number.

Comment: That definitely seems like a good interpretation. I thought that canonical was a concept in the 1985 standard, but upon looking it seems that is not the case. It seems like binary formats only being canonical is implied by the 1985 standard.